# Override JTextArea.getDocument.remove()?

Tags: java, swing, overriding, jtextarea

Okay, I want to override JTextArea's Document's remove method, I can't figure out what class to extend. I can't extend Document cause it's a interface, and that also means it must not be the document that JTextArea creates. So how exactly can I easily override my JTextArea's document's remove method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `Document` of a [`JTextArea`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) is [`PlainDocument`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html), as mentioned in [`createDefaultModel()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#createDefaultModel%28%29). Here is a simple [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/92253e51cff619b8) of overriding `insertString()` in [`PlainDocument`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DocumentFilter instead.